# Dataset for IAB taxonomy text classification?

Tags: classification

I'd like to train a system that takes text and predicts [IAB classes](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/iab-quality-assurance-guidelines-qag-taxonomy/).

Are there any public datasets available for this?

Comment: I am planning to create a dataset for this and make it public - can you let me know your requirements if you still have them 4 years on :)

Comment: Awesome!  I would still welcome a dataset for this.  I think ideally it would be a a multi-label dataset and (in a perfect world) would be for paragraph-sized text or smaller since aggregating up would be easier than detangling down.  As you get larger chunks the odds of needing multi-label would seem to increase too.  Good luck and let me know if there's a repo or something to track.

Comment: @dendog Is your dataset available? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I never got round to this, plus I feel now with LLMs and synth data - this is sort of solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/bpmtips/websiteiabcategorization

if you want to validate your model you can use this free api to validate results of your model

https://front-page.com/domain.php?domain=google.com

you just need to provide attribution to https://front-page.com

Comment: Also take a look at https://commonscreens.com, they have the already categorized data of 77 million domains and provide a training data set also.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for that as well and did not find any so far. But [this paper](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/47802/Ingrid_Guren.pdf?sequence=1) describes approach to use Wikipedia data for this.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Can you include the essentials here?