# Dataset labeled with IAB's content taxonomy categories

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Is there any dataset labeled with [IAB's content taxonomy categories](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/taxonomy/)?

I have some text data and I want to predict their categories based on IAB's content taxonomy.

Comment: See https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10608/dataset-for-iab-taxonomy-text-classification